# Asterisk using Customer CDRs with cdr_adaptive_odbc is not working

Tags: asterisk

I am having an issue in Asterisk 14.6.1 getting my custom CDR fields populated using ODBC to a MySQL database, basically I am making simultaneous outbound calls using Dial and I need to know in the CDRs which phone actually answered the call, so I am using a macro.

So here’s my simple extensions.conf

```
exten => 12345,1,Dial(PJSIP/071XXXXXXXX@EP&PJSIP/072XXXXXXXX@EP,180,M(test),r)
```

And my Macro:

```
[macro-test]
exten => s,1,Verbose(Call Answered from ${CALLERID(num)} to ${DIALEDPEERNUMBER})
exten => s,2,Set(CDR(outboundddi)=${DIALEDPEERNUMBER})
exten => s,3,Set(CDR(userfield)=${DIALEDPEERNUMBER})
```

So all this works fine, calls are ringing, being answered and macro running!

Output from Asterisk:

```
PJSIP/PrimaryEP-00000001 answered PJSIP/EP-00000000
– Executing [s@macro-test:1] Verbose(“PJSIP/EP-00000001”, “Call Answered from 12345 to 071XXXXXXXX@EP”) in new stack
Call Answered from 12345 to 071XXXXXXXX@EP
– Executing [s@macro-test:2] Set(“PJSIP/EP-00000001”, “CDR(outboundddi)= 071XXXXXXXX@EP”) in new stack
– Executing [s@macro-test:3] Set(“PJSIP/EP-00000001”, “CDR(userfield)= 071XXXXXXXX@EP”) in new stack
```

So I know all this works. The Set(CDR(userfield)=${DIALEDPEERNUMBER}) works fine, the Set(CDR(outboundddi)=${DIALEDPEERNUMBER}) does not, it appears to be ignored, and I do not get an error. So the value is getting populated in the userfield of the database, but nothing gets populated in the outboundddi field of the database.

I think it gets ignored because cdr_odbc is registered in the backend as well as cdr_adaptive_odbc - but if I noload cdr_odbc.so then I do not get any CDRs logged in the ODBC database, and if I take out the config in cdr_odbc.conf then again I get nothing on the ODBC database.

Here is some further detail:

cdr show status
    Call Detail Record (CDR) settings

```
Logging: Enabled
Mode: Simple
Log unanswered calls: Yes
Log congestion: Yes

Registered Backends
cdr-custom
cdr_manager (suspended)
radius
Adaptive ODBC
ODBC
res_config_sqlite
```

odbc show
    ODBC DSN Settings

```
Name: asterisk
DSN: Asterisk
Number of active connections: 1 (out of 1)
```

module reload cdr_adaptive_odbc.so

```
Module ‘cdr_adaptive_odbc.so’ reloaded successfully.
– Reloading module ‘cdr_adaptive_odbc.so’ (Adaptive ODBC CDR backend)
== Parsing ‘/etc/asterisk/cdr_adaptive_odbc.conf’: Found
– Found adaptive CDR table cdrs@asterisk.
> Found calldate column with type 93 with len 19, octetlen 19, and numlen (0,10)
> Found clid column with type 12 with len 80, octetlen 80, and numlen (0,0)
> Found src column with type 12 with len 80, octetlen 80, and numlen (0,0)
> Found dst column with type 12 with len 80, octetlen 80, and numlen (0,0)
> Found dcontext column with type 12 with len 80, octetlen 80, and numlen (0,0)
> Found channel column with type 12 with len 80, octetlen 80, and numlen (0,0)
> Found dstchannel column with type 12 with len 80, octetlen 80, and numlen (0,0)
> Found lastapp column with type 12 with len 80, octetlen 80, and numlen (0,0)
> Found lastdata column with type 12 with len 80, octetlen 80, and numlen (0,0)
> Found duration column with type 4 with len 10, octetlen 10, and numlen (0,10)
> Found billsec column with type 4 with len 10, octetlen 10, and numlen (0,10)
> Found disposition column with type 12 with len 45, octetlen 45, and numlen (0,0)
> Found amaflags column with type 4 with len 10, octetlen 10, and numlen (0,10)
> Found accountcode column with type 12 with len 20, octetlen 20, and numlen (0,0)
> Found userfield column with type 12 with len 255, octetlen 255, and numlen (0,0)
> Found uniqueid column with type 12 with len 32, octetlen 32, and numlen (0,0)
> Found linkedid column with type 12 with len 32, octetlen 32, and numlen (0,0)
> Found sequence column with type 12 with len 32, octetlen 32, and numlen (0,0)
> Found peeraccount column with type 12 with len 32, octetlen 32, and numlen (0,0)
> Found outboundddi column with type 12 with len 50, octetlen 50, and numlen (0,0)
```

cdr_adaptive_cdr.conf

```
[adaptive_connection]
connection=asterisk
table=cdrs
usegmtime=yes
```

cdr_odbc.conf

```
[global]
dsn=asterisk
loguniqueid=yes
dispositionstring=yes
table=cdrs ;“cdr” is default table name
usegmtime=yes ; set to “yes” to log in GMT
hrtime=yes ;Enables microsecond accuracy with the billsec and duration fields
newcdrcolumns=yes ; Enable logging of post-1.8 CDR columns (peeraccount, linkedid, sequence)
```

I guess I could just forget it and use the userfield that is working, but I’d rather it be stored in a custom CDR field and I’d like to know what is incorrect for my own sanity, so if anyone can point me into what I have configured incorrectly I would be most grateful.

Thanks

David

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have put aliases lines in cdr_adaptive_odbc.conf

```
alias start => calldate
```

No, it not scan table itself.